# php, appending to a semicolon text file while echoing the results back to the text input?

Tags: php, html

I'm having a hard time making my form work. Basically I want what is in the table cell to echo back to the form so it can  be appended if needed.

My construction is not working so I need help...

Here it is in 3 parts...
The var

```
<?php

$companyData = array();
   if (($handle = fopen("settings.txt", "w")) !== FALSE)
 {
   while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE)
    {
    if(substr(trim($data[0]), 0, 3) == 'DAT')
    {
        $board = trim($data[0]);
        $temp = $data[1];
        $companyData[ $board ] = $temp;
    }
 }
 fclose($handle);
 }
 $emailData = array();
  if (($handle = fopen("settings.txt", "w")) !== FALSE)
  {
 while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== FALSE)
   {
    if(substr(trim($data[0]), 0, 3) == 'DAT')
    {
        $board = trim($data[0]);
        $temp = $data[2];
        $emailData[ $board ] = $temp;
    }
 }
 fclose($handle);
  }
  ?>
```

The second part is the html...

```
<form action="settingsnew.php" method="post">
<table width="422">
  <tr align="center">

    <td colspan="2">CUSTOMER INFO</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>company name</td>
    <td><input name="company" type="text" id="company" value="<?php echo str_replace("<br />","",$companyData); ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>email (main)</td>
    <td><input name="email" type="text" id="email" value="<?php echo str_replace("<br />","",$emailData); ?>" /></td>
  </tr>
        <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input name="myBtn" type="submit" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

finally the database....

```
DAT 0; ONE ; TWO ;
```

My form obviously doesn't work, but I feel I'm close. Can anyone help me on this one?

Comment: What exactly should happen to the file when you submit the form? Show us a sample of the desired output. (And I do hope you have a good reason to use this clumsy storage mechanism instead of a proper database.)

Comment: On submit I wanted that whatever is in the text input box to be added to settings.txt and then that to be echoed back to the text input box. This is basically an edit form... :/

Comment: Added how exactly? Please show us a sample of the file before and after the submit, the way you want it to look like. Your "ONE, TWO" values in your current sample are not helpful at all.

Comment: So, right now it's not working because it's not echoing ONE, and TWO, but if I type in THREE and FOUR, then it should replace the ONE and TWO in the respective columns.

Comment: What are ONE and TWO? Companies or emails? You keep ignoring my suggestions to show us an example of a desired output, forcing me to ask more and more questions instead.

Comment: Dude, just wanted to do this with php and not python (my specialty)... It shouldn't be that difficult... Just want to APPEND a file that has a semicolon table in it like the example I showed... Two simple things, appending a file and echoing the results in the table back to the text input. Thanks anyway.